# Android_ID alternative in Android O

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-identifiers

With the changes in Android O, ANDROID_ID is now scoped per app signing key, as well as per user. Factory resetting the device will also generate new ANDROID_ID value.

My questions is, what other alternative ID (that's more potent) does you folks use aside from Android ID?

I did some research learnt that Google suggested us to use AdvertisingId, but user can reset their AdvertisingId anytime they want.

I have also looked at the Key/Value backup to backup the existing Android ID and associate it and new values. This approach is good, but the backup is associated with a Google account. So this does not work if the user resets the device and sign-in with a different Google account.

My goal here is to get a device specific identifier to be used for fraud/malicious detection and I am having a difficult time trying to gauge what kind of identifier to use. I know that I can just use IMEI, but Google recommended to avoid using it and it also requires `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.

Comment: "this does not work if the user resets the device and sign-in with a different Google account" -- so? This also happens when you sell the device, give it to a younger sibling, donate it to a charitable organization, etc. The original user resets the device, transfers it to somebody else, who then signs in with their own account (or uses it sans an account). By your argument, the device recipient is engaging in fraud.

Comment: there is no such thing as a device specific ID anymore, though there really wasn't ever one that never changed

Answer (score 0):

[Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html) article has a dedicated use-case for Anti-fraud:

> **Anti-fraud: Enforcing free content limits and detecting Sybil attacks**
>
> *In this case, you want to limit the number of free
>   content, such as articles, that a user can see on a device.*
>
> **Use:** Instance ID or GUID. On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher,
>   SSAID is also an option, as it's scoped to the app-signing key.
>
> **Why this recommendation?**
>
> Using a GUID or Instance ID forces the user to reinstall the app in
>   order to circumvent the content limits, which is a sufficient burden
>   to deter most people. If this isn't sufficient protection, Android
>   provides a DRM API, which can be used to limit access to content,
>   includes a per-APK identifier, the Widevine ID.

Note that SSAID == Storage.Secure.ANDROID_ID.